# Laptop number pad not working

Tags: toshiba-satellite

Installed Ubuntu latest version on my Toshiba Satellite P875 and I can not get my number pad to work. Number lock is on but numbers don't type. The +/− and enter keys work only.

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting and during boot sequence mash the number pad keys sometimes parts of HID's are not active at boot and do not get recognized let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It worked however when I 'woke up' the laptop, number pad wasn't working again.  Also, I just got a bluetooth mouse and paired it and now every time I 'wake up' the laptop I have to go thru the pairing process each time.

Comment: wow it worked and someone gave me a negative point thanks..

Comment: You will have to do that at start up each time you want to use those keys as that is when onboard HID's are decected such as touchpads, touchscreens, and keyboards. when you installed ubuntu did you make sure that the keyboard layout was that of your region?